# Extract and select links from webpage

Tags: html, ios, regex, shortcut

There is a website that I visit daily called thegudda.com, this website posts lots videos on a daily basis so instead of going through the website and clicking link by link, I wanna make an iOS shortcut that select all the video links at once on the webpage then I can choose all of them and open them in new tabs... What I got so far: ^https://www.thegudda.com/(.*)([A-Za-z]+)\b(?

https://www.thegudda.com/crazy-bird-attacking-people-and-one-dude-ended-up-paying-the-price/
https://www.thegudda.com/crazy-bird-attacking-people-and-one-dude-ended-up-paying-the-price/
https://www.thegudda.com/that-look-on-his-face-what-do-you-think-kanyes-thinking-in-this-moment/
https://www.thegudda.com/that-look-on-his-face-what-do-you-think-kanyes-thinking-in-this-moment/

while I just want each link one time...

Comment: What I got so far: ^https:\/\/www\.thegudda\.com\/(.*)([A-Za-z]+)\b(?<!page|contact|\?p|#website|organization|feed|comment|wp-json)

Comment: Why not just add a filter to your array or a for loop that removes duplicates? Looks like your regex is fine

Comment: Thanks @BrandonStillitano... how do I do that ?

Answer (score -1):

you can put them in Set, the Sets by default removes the duplicate elements.
you can see more about Sets here:
 https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html
in Sets section

Comment: This question is about iOS Shortcuts, not Swift.